# Failed to change Amazon's shipping address using the requests module

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

If I check on this [website](https://www.amazon.co.uk/), I can see an option "Deliver to" on the top left of that site. Depending on the country I viewed the site from, the site automatically changes that location. I wish to change that location to "United States". I've created a script in Python to change the address to the aforesaid one.

However, when I execute the script, I get "Deliver to Bangladesh" as an output instead of "Deliver to United States."

I've tried with:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

start_url = 'https://www.amazon.co.uk/'
cookie_consent_url = 'https://www.amazon.co.uk/privacyprefs/retail/v1/acceptall'
location_changer_url = 'https://www.amazon.co.uk/portal-migration/hz/glow/address-change?actionSource=glow'
location_details_checker_url = 'https://www.amazon.co.uk/portal-migration/hz/glow/get-location-label?storeContext=generic&pageType=Gateway&actionSource=desktop-modal'

headers = {
    'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'accept': 'application/json',
}
params = {
    'anti-csrftoken-a2z': '',
    'accept': 'all'
}
payload = {"locationType":"COUNTRY","district":"US","countryCode":"US","storeContext":"generic","deviceType":"web","pageType":"Gateway","actionSource":"glow"}

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers.update(headers)
    res = s.get(start_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')
    params['anti-csrftoken-a2z'] = soup.select_one("input[name='anti-csrftoken-a2z']")['value']
    resp = s.post(cookie_consent_url,data=params)
    res = s.post(location_changer_url,json=payload)
    response = s.get(location_details_checker_url)
    print(response.json()['deliveryShortLine'])
```

Current output (shows the default country I executed the script from):

```
Deliver to Bangladesh
```

Expected output:

```
Deliver to United States
```

Comment: This has to do with your IP address, not the payload. Apparently, your IP comes from Bangladesh, hence the country of delivery. Using proxy or VPN should help.

Comment: When I change the shipping address manually on that site and verify the result [here](https://www.amazon.co.uk/portal-migration/hz/glow/get-location-label?storeContext=generic&pageType=Gateway&actionSource=desktop-modal), I can see the expected output accordingly.

Comment: Have you tried my solution given to your latest question?

Comment: The key issue is to use functions to wrap the whole thing up while scraping content from inner sites and moving on to the next pages by clicking the next page button @Prophet.

Comment: So, you want me to get the `title` and `skill` values there too, not only the links? I can add this too